# error in building a docker image from my react project

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I followed [this documentation](https://dev.to/luizcalaca/dockerize-a-react-app-with-node-and-nginx-and-how-to-push-an-image-to-docker-hub-l9g) to dockerize my react app and I did everything as it said, but I get this `ERROR: failed to solve: circular dependency detected on stage: prod`  when try to execute `docker image build -t react:v1 .`

this is my Dockerfile (exactly as documentation)

```
FROM node AS prod
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
# RUN npm test - if you want to test before to build
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine AS prod
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=prod /app/build .
EXPOSE 80
# run nginx with global directives and daemon off
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and this is .dockerignore

```
/node_modules
```

I'm also using Ubuntu on vmware workstation.

Comment: Looks you are using same alias for both the stages. `FROM nginx:alpine AS prod` change this into `FROM nginx:alpine AS nginx-prod` and try.

Comment: The final stage doesn't need a name and you can delete the `AS ...` part of its `FROM` line as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use multi-stage builds, name's stage must be unique in Dockerfile. `prod` was be used in 2 stages in your script, just change one of them

```
FROM node AS prod # node-prod
...
FROM nginx:alpine AS prod # nginx-prod
```

See more at [here](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-multi-stage-builds)

Answer (score 0):

You have the same stage name for both the stages as this causes the circular dependency error.

Change one of them

```
FROM nginx:alpine AS prod
```

into

```
FROM nginx:alpine AS nginx-prod
```